# Checking CheckBoxField in Gridview with VS 2010 in ASP.NET

Tags: gridview, checkbox

I'm trying to have a gridview with a checkboxfield in it that identifies the row as either completed or not. However, when the gridview loads, the checkboxes are greyed out, and when I use an "edit" link to update the record with a check, the check does not save in the checkbox.  Any ideas?

Comment: I guess another way to phrase my question is how do I have a checkbox column and have the checked or not checked property permanently written into the database?